# Can the View call the Model in a MVC-structure in Java?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

I'm making a basic MVC structure in Java and I'm wondering if the view is allowed to call the model for information?

For example: A user clicks a button that is created in the View. The View calls the Controller which has a handler that tells him what to do next. Then the Controller calls a method in the Model, and sends a value also. At the same time the Controller calls the method "UpdateLabel" in the View. Now is allowed to call a method in the Model from the "UpdateLabel" method in the View, so the View can use the value that's stored in the Model?

Thanks in advance for reading and responding to my question!

Comment: Why in Java? I believe that MVC structure doesn't matter the language that you use.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the View call the Model in a MVC-structure in Java?

It can but it should not. If it does, it won't be MVC anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the view should use the getters of the model, but not the others.

The model should be passed in a non-tightly coopeled fashion like you achieve with the observer pattern. Basicly the observer pattern's listener paramater should contain your model, or an event class containing your model. Ofcource these are only guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Can the view call the model: Yes. *Should* the view call model is really what your question should be :-)

I tend to take the pragmatic approach and allow view code to show/hide/scroll/slide whatever part of the model known to it, but I set the limit at actually manipulating the model - that is left to the controller...

I'm sure you'll get other takes on that, and likely most of them will be more stringent than me.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant `Should the View call the Model`. Thank you.